# Weird flickr on sticky header on mobile devices & tablets

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, swipe

I've pulled my hair out for weeks, literally, trying to troubleshoot this issue. There's a lot going on, so I'll try to explain as best I can. But what I'm trying to solve is a weird flickr in the site's sticky navigation, when swiping up/down the page on a mobile device or tablet. It only does this on two pages, so I know there's a conflict with the sticky header jQuery and some other javascript functions on those pages.

So a little background: we're using this [Mobile Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) PHP class to detect mobile and tablet browsers. We're also using the jQuery mobile library to utilize swiping gestures to swipe through image sliders. The main page that I'm running into the issue with though is the Work page: http://hybridmediadesign.com/work, which has no sliders, but does use [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/).

It seems that the jQuery mobile library is what's causing the flicker, because removing it eliminates the flicker. It's like when you tap or swipe your device, it randomly causes the header navigation to go lose its persistent class.

So I don't even know what code to show here, but here's the jQuery used for the sticky header:

```
<script>
window.weAreLoaded = false;
(function($) {
    var documentBind = ($.browser.mobile == true ? 'pageinit' : 'ready');

    $(document).bind(documentBind, function() {
        if(!weAreLoaded) {
            $(window).scroll(function(e) {
                var position = $.browser.webkit ? e.target.body.scrollTop : e.target.documentElement.scrollTop, header_height = 124;

                if ($(window).width() > 540) {
                    if (position >= header_height) {

                        if (!$('body').hasClass('persistent')) {
                            $('body').addClass('persistent').css('padding-top', 55);
                            $('.persistent header').animate({
                                'top' : 0
                            }, 600);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $('.persistent header').css('top', '-69px');
                        $('body').removeClass('persistent').css('padding-top', 0);
                    }
                }
            });

</script>
```

I'm not sure what to even paste here to give you an idea of where the conflict is coming from, so if you have any clue as to where to start just ask me for teh codez.

And lastly, the super sucky thing is that you can't recreate this issue in a desktop browser. Even changing the UA doesn't recreate the issue. I literally have to pull out my iPhone and test, which is terrible because I'm just shooting in the dark trying to fix stuff. Ahhh!!

**Update**
[Here's the link to the full javascript file used throughout the site.](http://www.hybridmediadesign.com/wp-content/themes/hybrid/custom.js)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this at the first html page that jquery mobile is instantiated at ?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

That resolved flickering issues on my app running jquery mobile. Also jquery mobile 1.3.1 caused some flickers so I'm sticking to 1.3.0. for now.

Also you can use 'vclick' to replace both 'tap' and 'click', jquery will detect on what platform it is running so tap will be used if it is a mobile platform.

Comment: Yes to the meta tag. Although yours is repeating ```maximum-scale``` twice. I'm using the 1.2.1 jQuery mobile library. Will try upgrading.